# error with the add with parameter function c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Additional information**:

The parameterized query '`(@challan_no int,@job_name nvarchar(4000),@paper_stock_name nvar'` expects the parameter `@job_name`, which was not supplied. it keeps on showing this I don't exactly know whats wrong with the code I used references from stack overflow only to code this.

```
 cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO challan_print_sub (challan_no,job_name,paper_stock_name,size,quantity,rate,amount,sno,book_no) VALUES(@challan_no,@job_name,@paper_stock_name,@size,@quantity,@rate,@amount,@sno,@book_no)");
            cmd3.Connection = cnn;
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@challan_no", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@job_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@paper_stock_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@size", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@rate", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@amount", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@sno", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@book_no", SqlDbType.Int);
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
            cmd3.Parameters["@challan_no"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            cmd3.Parameters["@job_name"].Value = Convert.ToString(job_name[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@paper_stock_name"].Value = Convert.ToString(pap_sto_name[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@size"].Value = Convert.ToString(size[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(quantity[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@rate"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(rate[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@amount"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(amount[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@sno"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(snu[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@book_no"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();}                }
```

Comment: it does work when I remove all the parameter command from the for loop

Comment: Why @book_no has no value ?

Comment: `cmd3.Parameters["@book_no"].Value =`  is missing .

Comment: yes I was about to do that but error is not about it

Comment: the same error exist after making the change

Comment: Use `job_name[j] != null ? job_name[j] : DBNull.Value;;` It seems some array `jjob_name` is null or empty string

Comment: You're using `AddWithValue` but you're passing the type and not the value except for job_name, use `.Add` instead.

Comment: Checked the edited answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `AddWithValue` but you're passing the type and not the value. You need to use `.Add`. Since you're using that except for `@job_name` where you use `.Add`, SQL assumes you're passing the value for all parameters except this one. Notice that for NULL parameters you need to use `DBNull.Value` To Solve this:

```
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@challan_no", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@job_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@paper_stock_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@size", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@rate", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@amount", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@sno", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@book_no", SqlDbType.Int);

for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
{
    object jobName = job_name[j];
    if (jobName == null)
        jobName = DBNull.Value;


    cmd3.Parameters["@challan_no"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters["@job_name"].Value = jobName;
    cmd3.Parameters["@paper_stock_name"].Value = Convert.ToString(pap_sto_name[j]);
    cmd3.Parameters["@size"].Value = Convert.ToString(size[j]);
    cmd3.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(quantity[j]);
    cmd3.Parameters["@rate"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(rate[j]);
    cmd3.Parameters["@amount"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(amount[j]);
    cmd3.Parameters["@sno"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(snu[j]);
    cmd3.Parameters"@book_no"].Value = 0; // Change this to some input
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: ?? cannot be applied to operand of type string and dbnull

Comment: @Himanshu check the edit. You need to use `.Add()` and not `AddWithValue`

Comment: type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is not implicit conversion between string and system.dbnull

Comment: @Himanshu Read the answer again to know where your problem is.

Comment: its an exception of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException and additional information same as above

Comment: Please post the edited code that you're using now in your question (Edit your question and add the code at the end)

Comment: I have  edited it please help me with this as soon as possible

Comment: @Himanshu Is it the same error `expects the parameter @job_name` ?

Comment: @Himanshu add the if statement that I added to the answer. It should do the trick . SQL treats NULL parameters as if it is not passed.

Comment: I found the mistake thanks for the support I was just doing a mistake with the array wherein the array was null for a value that's why I was getting the error thank u so very much I already ticked the ans

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO challan_print_sub (challan_no,job_name,paper_stock_name,size,quantity,rate,amount,sno,book_no) VALUES(@challan_no,@job_name,@paper_stock_name,@size,@quantity,@rate,@amount,@sno,@book_no)");
            cmd3.Connection = cnn;
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@challan_no", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@job_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@paper_stock_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@size", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@rate", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@amount", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@sno", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@book_no", SqlDbType.Int);
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
            cmd3.Parameters["@challan_no"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            cmd3.Parameters["@job_name"].Value =job_name[j];
            cmd3.Parameters["@paper_stock_name"].Value = Convert.ToString(pap_sto_name[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@size"].Value = Convert.ToString(size[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(quantity[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@rate"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(rate[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@amount"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(amount[j]);
            cmd3.Parameters["@sno"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(snu[j]);
            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```